# Como mostrar los usuarios seleccionados

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando mostrar los usuarios selecionados mediante un **seleccion multiple**, pero solo me retorna el ultimo valor seleccionado.

Este es mi codigo en donde mando los datos seleccionados en la vista:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="form-group">
            <select  name="operador[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Usuarios" style="width: 100%;">
                 @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
                 <option value="{{$usuario->id}}">{{$usuario->name}}</option>
                  @endforeach
             </select>
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->
     </div>
```

Y en el **Controller** hago el recorrido de esta forma:

```
$idoperador = $request->input("operador");
     $usuarios = [];
            foreach ($idoperador as $usuario){

              $usuarios= DB::table("users")
                            ->where("id","=",$usuario)
                            ->get();    
            }
            return view('verificar.listaCorte', compact(['usuarios']));
```

Esta es la vista en donde recibo los datos del **controller**

```
                  <th>Operador</th>

                  <th></th>
                </tr>
                    @foreach($usuarios as $listado)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{$listado->name}}</td>
                </tr>
                 @endforeach
              </table>
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: La variable $usuarios dentro del foreach se está reescribiendo en cada ciclo. Echale un vistazo al método **whereIn()** creo que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Deberías agregarlo como respuesta @Xerif, lo que planteas es una mejor solución que la respuesta actual. Te daré mi +1

Comment: @Xerif, me manda el siguiente error al usar el metodo **whereIn()** : `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Siento no haber podido contestarte o no haberte dado una respuesta. Estoy con el móvil. Conseguiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Si ya lo solucione gracias por la recomendación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la sentencia `whereIn`

```
$usuarios = DB::table("users")->whereIn("id", $request->operador)
            ->get();

return view('verificar.listaCorte', compact('usuarios'));
```

Answer (score 1):

En el controlador cuando haces la consulta por el id del usuario estás sobreescribiendo la variable $usuarios, de ahí que siempre te muestre el último seleccionado.
Yo probaría algo como esto:

```
$idoperador = $request->input("operador");
     $usuarios = [];
            foreach ($idoperador as $usuario){

              array_push($usuarios,DB::table("users")
                            ->where("id","=",$usuario)
                            ->get());    
            }
            return view('verificar.listaCorte', compact(['usuarios']));
```

De este modo añadimos el elemento (nuestro caso, un registro de base de datos) al final del array $usuarios, sin sobreescribirlo.

Comment: No me queda claro lo que quieres decir con "machacarlo", ¿podrías utilizar una palabra más genérica? por favor.

Comment: Buenas, me refiero a que cada vez que realiza la iteración, esta dandole el valor del registro a la variable, imagina que le hace lo siguiente: array[0] = valor; array[0] = valor2; cuando en realidad debería ser array[0] = valor; array[1] = valor2;

Comment: Buen dia hice uso de array_push y al realizar la consulta me arroja el siguiente mensaje. Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sim\resources\views\verificar\listaCorte.blade.php) @Shanz